# django clear redisco for testing

Tags: django, redis

We are using Redisco for our models, and I am writing some tests for our models, however redis keeps filling up, so for each test, more data is added to reddis.

Is there a way to clear Redis for each test, and what are the best practices when testing (using redis and redisco)

## - EDIT -

This is the solution I went with in the end, and I want to share this with others who might have the same question

To make sure each test case is running on a clean Redis instance, start each test case by running

```
redis = Redis()
redis.flushall()
```

As people have commented below, make sure you don't run the tests against a production instance of Redis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend running a second redis instance for testing (eg. on a different port...) so you are also not able to accidentally drop any production data from your redis when running tests.

You could then use custom `BaseTestClass` which overrides your project's settings (in the `setUp` method - you can also emtpy your redis' dbs there) so that they point to another redis instance (hopefully you've defined your redis connections in your project's settings) and have all your test classes inherit from this base class.

Comment: Would it be suitable to call redis = Redis() and redis.flushall() in each test case?

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of dealing with side-effects such as connecting to a database in unit tests is to provide a mock implementation of the data layer during the test. This can be done in many ways, you could use a different redis instance, or dynamically override methods to report to your test rather than actually manipulating the database etc.

Dependancy Injection is a pattern used for this kind of problem, more often in static languages like Java, but there are tools for Python, see http://code.google.com/p/snake-guice/